# Host Multiple Angular 7 Apps in a Single AWS S3 Bucket

Tags: angular, amazon-s3

How can I host multiple Angular 7 apps in a single AWS S3 bucket? i.e.

Each site to be in subfolder:

```
/site1
/site2
/site3
```

Each site to be accessed by subfolder:

```
www.mydomain.com/site1
www.mydomain.com/site2
www.mydomain.com/site3
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For your Angular build you need to ensure that the [base href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base) is set correctly. A sample for `site1` would be built with the below command. (Documentation [here](https://angular.io/cli/build))

   `ng build --baseHref /site1/`
2. Make sure static website hosting on your S3 bucket is enabled with index document set to `index.html`.
3. Create 3 folders in `S3` with `site1`, `site2`, `site3`.
4. Put all the contents of your Angular build into those folders i.e. for `site1` upload `index.html` and `all bundles` into `site1` folder on `S3` and similarly for other folders. (At this point you can access the angular apps with S3 urls)
5. You also need to have your DNS mapping for www.mydomain.com to the s3 bucket.

Read the AWS documentation on [static hosting on S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html) with custom domain.

Comment: Perfect. This is the zen type answer I was hoping for that cuts through the years of posts/comments/bugs that have surrounded this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Additional information to the accepted answer above:

In an Ionic environment, ionic build ignores the baseHref parameter. However, there is a workaround (note the additional double dash:

```
ionic build --prod -- --baseHref /site1/
```

When using the baseHref build param the index.html base tag is set to this path. This was how I could tell if the baseHref build param was working or not  e.g.

```
<base href="/site1/" />
```

It was NOT necessary to also use Angular build flag deployUrl.

Using this asset path in html resolved my asset 404 issues:

```
<img src="assets/myimage.png">
```

One issue yet to resolve: refreshing a page of the app results in a 404 even though S3 static website hosting is setup with error document = index.html (see screenshot below). An app published to the S3 root refreshes okay. Note that this is NOT a recommended approach in a production environment but is a quick work-around.

[image]

Comment: Are you using HashLocationStrategy?

Comment: No using PathLocationStrategy.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish this using different angular versions for each app (v8, v12, v13):

**Angular App Settings (per app)**

1. Inside `angular.json` add `"baseHref":"/{appName}/"` under project > architect > build > options.

```
...
    "architect": {
        "build": {
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/app1/",
            "outputPath": "dist/",
            ...
...
```

2. In `app.module` add provider

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF, PlatformLocation } from '@angular/common'; // top of file
...
...
    providers: [
    {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF,
      useFactory: getBaseHref,
      deps: [PlatformLocation]
    },
    ...
   ]
...
...
/**
 * This function is used internal to get a string instance of the `<base href="" />` value from `index.html`.
 * This is an exported function, instead of a private function or inline lambda, to prevent this error:
 *
 * `Error encountered resolving symbol values statically.`
 * `Function calls are not supported.`
 * `Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function.`
 *
 * @param platformLocation an Angular service used to interact with a browser's URL
 * @return a string instance of the `<base href="" />` value from `index.html`
 */
export function getBaseHref(platformLocation: PlatformLocation): string {
  return platformLocation.getBaseHrefFromDOM();
}
```

3. Run `ng build` and verify a `dist` folder was created.

**AWS S3 Bucket Settings**

1. Create an S3 Bucket (one per Domain/Client, not application)
2. Create folders inside S3 Bucket (app1, app2, app3)
3. Manually upload contents from `dist` folder (all files inside the folder, not the folder itself). Repeat for each application.
4. Enable "Static website hosting" on the S3 Bucket.
5. Set Index AND Error document to `index.html`
6. Copy the HTTP endpoint domain (ex. `{S3_BUCKET_NAME}.s3-website-{AWS_REGION}.amazonaws.com`)

**AWS Cloudfront Settings**

1. Create CloudFront Distribution
2. Create 1 Origin per application. Point Origin Domain to S3 HTTP endpoint above. Protocol is `HTTP only`. Origin path should remain *empty*.
3. Create 2 Behaviors per application. Path should be set to `/{APP_NAME}` and `/{APP_NAME}/*` for the other behavior. Origin should match the Origin from previous step.
4. Setup *Error pages* for 400, 403, and 404. Set *Response page path* to `/index.html` and set *HTTP response code* to 200.

Comment: When you click refresh in the browser does the app reload or show a 404 error page.

Comment: It shows 404. Bummer. Found a different article that tries to address the refresh issue here: https://andrewlock.net/using-lambda-at-edge-to-handle-angular-client-side-routing-with-s3-and-cloudfront/